# Wolfram Alpha: How to show functions with abs() and sgn() as a piecewise function?

Tags: integration, math-software, wolfram-alpha

I was trying to obtain this result:

```
integrate e^|x| dx
```

[The result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5e|x|+dx) is

$$ \int e^{|x|} dx = \frac12 e^{-x} \left( (e^x-1)^2 \operatorname{sgn}(x) -2e^x +e^{2x} - 1 \right) \color{gray}{\,+ \text{constant}} $$

which is fine but I would like to see the 2 part solution for $x>0$ and $x<0$, I know you can see that because just after before the final output I can see it but then it switches to the one line solution above.
Is there a way to see the other solution?

If it's not ok to ask about a tool used in mathematics I'm sorry. You can close it.

Comment: Well, you can derive it yourself; $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ is expressible as a piecewise function.

Comment: I cannot see what you are asking here... «The other solution» is the same as the solution you have.

Comment: btw, Wolfram Alpha uses Mathematica as a backend, you may need to use Mathematica syntax to get more advanced things out of it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, giving the input

`Integrate[Exp[Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}}, -x]],x]`

to WolframAlpha returns a piecewise result, which may be what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the two cases:

```
Assuming[t>0, integrate e^|x| dx from x=0 to t]
Assuming[t<0, integrate e^|x| dx from x=0 to t]
```

Or, if you don't care about choosing the constant of integration such that the two pieces fit together, simply:

```
Assuming[x>0, integrate e^|x| dx]
Assuming[x<0, integrate e^|x| dx]
```

(although then it's so easy that I don't see why you would need Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: I'm playing with the tool :D I was testing something "complicated" from the point of view of the tool, not the math, to see how flexible it is.

Comment: BTW nice workaround but since I see the solution I want just before it switches on the one line solution, I would like to see the 2part solution without giving it a restraint on the variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "seeing the solution"? For me, Alpha just spits out the answer that you quoted in the question. (No "switching" going on.)

Comment: There's a tiny moment, it's a one second switch. Clear your cache, maybe that's the problem. Or try with `integrate e^-|x| dx
` which has a slower process.

Comment: Nope, didn't make any difference. Well, never mind...

Comment: Don't worry. Tnx. It's there, I've seen that, the truth is out there.